# Firebase 502 Server Error: Bad Gateway

Tags: python, firebase

When I post data to firebase via python from time to time I get the error:

```
HTTPError: 502 Server Error: Bad Gateway
```

This seems to be random. I can't identify the reason. Sometimes I have also problems getting data from firebase via c#. After some retries it works.

Comment: can you give us more details about the code that you worked on?

Answer (score -1):

(Adding as an answer - cant add a comment-lack of reputation)

This is a very old question, but just in case someone is looking for something similar.

I have a similar problem using python - random errors to mostly firebase but then I saw it happened during other network operations - once an operation on elasticsearch and once when trying to send an email
The errors seen related to firebase

```
502 Server Error: Bad Gateway for url: **********/created.json
Reason: Internal server error

OR 


HTTPSConnectionPool(host='stylemates-int.firebaseio.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: *******************
Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa8baf54198>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)).
```

This is on an ubuntu instance running on AWS EC2. Checking the system logs at the same time the error occurred shows that the OS is trying to renew the IP. This is corresponds to everytime there was a firebase error or any other n/w error
This linux instance is used for dev testing on AWS EC2 with dynamic IP. I am hoping that setting a static IP for this linux instance would fix the problem. I will not be able to try this for a few days since the machine cannot be reset at the moment. Will post results after I try it out.

Ubuntu logs

```
$ sudo journalctl --since "2019-05-13 09:50:00" --until "2019-05-13 09:50:59"
-- Logs begin at Sat 2019-03-16 22:22:42 UTC, end at Mon 2019-05-13 13:37:41 UTC. --
May 13 09:50:09 ip-172-32-1-88 dhclient[930]: DHCPREQUEST of 172.32.1.88 on eth0 to 172.32.0.1 port 67 (xid=********)
May 13 09:50:09 ip-172-32-1-88 dhclient[930]: DHCPACK of 172.32.1.88 from 172.32.0.1
May 13 09:50:09 ip-172-32-1-88 systemd[1]: Stopping Network Name Resolution...
May 13 09:50:09 ip-172-32-1-88 systemd[1]: Stopped Network Name Resolution.
May 13 09:50:09 ip-172-32-1-88 systemd[1]: Starting Network Name Resolution...
May 13 09:50:10 ip-172-32-1-88 systemd-resolved[11278]: Positive Trust Anchors:
May 13 09:50:10 ip-172-32-1-88 systemd-resolved[11278]: . IN *****
May 13 09:50:10 ip-172-32-1-88 systemd-resolved[11278]: . IN *****
May 13 09:50:10 ip-172-32-1-88 systemd-resolved[11278]: Negative trust anchors: *****
May 13 09:50:10 ip-172-32-1-88 systemd-resolved[11278]: Using system hostname 'ip-172-32-1-88'.
May 13 09:50:10 ip-172-32-1-88 systemd[1]: Started Network Name Resolution.
May 13 09:50:10 ip-172-32-1-88 systemd[1]: Starting resolvconf-pull-resolved.service...
May 13 09:50:10 ip-172-32-1-88 systemd[1]: Started resolvconf-pull-resolved.service.
May 13 09:50:10 ip-172-32-1-88 dhclient[930]: bound to 172.32.1.88 -- renewal in 1517 seconds.
```